# copy from clipboard and tranform to comma separated string

Tags: r

I am trying to copy a single column dataframe from an excel spreadsheet and transform in R as a comma separated list.

```
read.table(file = "clipboard") %>% as.list()
```

the desired output would be `a,b,c,d,e,f`

Comment: Hello, it worked ! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file = "clipboard"` looks for a file named `clipboard`. You need to change `file` to `text` and then use `readClipboard()` (without quotes). The next step is to `unlist` the values and then convert into a single string using `paste`

```
read.table(text = readClipboard()) %>% unlist %>% paste(collapse = ",")
#[1] "a,b,c,d,e,f"
```

Something like `paste(readClipboard(), collapse = ",")` could work too.